# PyOpenCL | Fail to launch a Kernel

Tags: python, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, pyopencl

When I'm using PyOpenCL to run the kernel "SIMPLE_JOIN" it fails.

**HEADER OF THE KERNEL IN .CL FILE**

```
void SIMPLE_JOIN(__global const int* a, int a_col, __global const int* a_valuesPic,
                 __global const int* b, int b_col, __global const int* b_valuesPic,
                __global const int* join_valuesPic, __global int* current, const int maxVars, __global int* buffer, int joinVar)
```

**THE EXECUTION IN PyOpenCL**

```
program.SIMPLE_JOIN(context, (a_col, b_col), None,  \
                    buffer_a, np.int32(a_col), buffer_a_valPic, \
                    buffer_b, np.int32(b_col), buffer_b_valPic, \
                    buffer_join_valPic, buffer_current, np.int32(maxVars), \
                    buffer_result, np.int32(joinList[0]))
```

**THE ERROR IN THE COMMAND LINE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2199, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1638, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/��/Documents/��������/GAP+/gapQueryTree.py", line 213, in <module>
    res1_array, res1_ValsPic = gpu.gpu_join(p[0], p1_ValsPic, friend[0], friend1_ValsPic)
  File "C:/Users/��/Documents/��������/GAP+\gapPyOpenCl.py", line 107, in gpu_join
    buffer_result, np.int32(joinList[0]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 515, in kernel_call
    global_offset, wait_for, g_times_l=g_times_l)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    pyopencl._cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(Context, Kernel, tuple, NoneType, NoneType, NoneType)
did not match C++ signature:
    enqueue_nd_range_kernel(class pyopencl::command_queue {lvalue} queue, class pyopencl::kernel {lvalue} kernel, class boost::python::api::object global_work_size, class boost::python::api::object local_work_size, class boost::python::api::object global_work_offset=None, class boost::python::api::object wait_for=None, bool g_times_l=False)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to your kernel invocation should be the command queue, not the context:

`program.SIMPLE_JOIN(`**`queue`**`, (a_col, b_col), None,  \...`

Comment: after that, the code doesn't appear to run. It means that after reading from buffers the arrays are still the same.

Comment: @user2287947 OK, that sounds like there is also a problem with your kernel code or the way in which you are reading data back to the host. You could open a new question if you need help investigating that.

Comment: the kernel works with opencl4py, BUT with pyOpenCL (i need to translate it later to pyCUDA) it doesn't work at all.

Comment: The author of this answer, ie James Price, has a rather neat debugger, ie https://github.com/jprice/Oclgrind , which you could try using to debug your program interactively :-)